# Airflow ECS - override the image tag when using EcsOperator

Tags: airflow, boto3, amazon-ecs

I'm using ECS Operator in Airflow and I want to run task_definition with a specific image tag.

ECS Operator is using `run_task()` method in `boto3`, and it is possible to overrides some of the task definition parameters.
I can't find a way to override the `image:tag`.

Does anyone know if it is possible to run a task with a specific image version? or other technics how to control which version of the image to use without using the latest or the tag that is defined in the task definition?

Comment: It's not possible to override the image. This is the documentation for the ECS run task override options: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_TaskOverride.html